# Importing Bahrain building footprints from Bing Maps into QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, csv, footprint, building

How can I import vector Building Footprints into QGIS from the Open Sourced updated Bing Footprints found here: https://minedbuildings.blob.core.windows.net/global-buildings/dataset-links.csv - maybe as an easily importable JSON file? I am specifically looking for the building footprints for Bahrain. Is there perhaps a QGIS plugin which imports csv.gz files into QGIS? There is a guide however this makes it more confusing as I am not familiar with Python: https://github.com/microsoft/GlobalMLBuildingFootprints/blob/main/scripts/make-gis-friendly.py

Answer (score 1):

The easier way is to download the .gz csv files

example:

```
https://minedbuildings.blob.core.windows.net/global-buildings/2022-11-15/global-buildings.geojsonl/RegionName%3DBahrain/quadkey%3D123023020/part-00119-2cb4a5ad-6652-48b0-a336-f09518f4c9e5.c000.csv.gz
```

unzip the file and rename the .csv to .geojson

load into qgis.

**Note: you will want to check the quality of the building polygons - you will need to clean up the data.**

[image]